# How to properly format text inside of a Android Toast

Tags: android

So I have info that I need to display inside of a Toast.

Here is the code in which I create the toast currently:

```
String toastFormat = "%-20s %-15s%n";
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Kultuur", "100 tera mass, g"));
        strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Talinisu", "min. 36"));
        strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Suvinisu", "min. 35"));
        strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Söödaoder", "min. 38"));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : strings) {
            builder.append(s);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the last elements in the second column tend to get indented a bit farther than they should be.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the format of the second column, its distance from the frist column is always the same. It looks like unformatted text because the strings on the first column have different number of characters. As a workaround, provide the second column strings as much white spaces at the beginning as the character count between the largest string in your first column and the string of that line. Example:

```
strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Kultuur", "  100 tera mass, g"));
strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Talinisu", "  min. 36"));
strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Suvinisu", " min. 35"));
strings.add(String.format(toastFormat, "Söödaoder", "min. 38"));
```

Try changing the spces until you get the desired aspect. It's ugly but works.

Comment: This seems easier than the first answer but both are correct. Thank you for the answer. I will have to see which one will work better for me.

Comment: I guess CommonsWare solution is of course more elegant, but in this case mine would be easier to implement. :)

Comment: Actually, the other answer doesn't provide 'relevant part of' the solution link  (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), so I still prefer this one despite being far from elegant.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You do not control the font used for a `Toast`, and usually a `Toast` will be shown in a proportional font (i.e., not monospace).

Since `Toast` accepts a `CharSequence`, you're welcome to try custom spans, like [those from Chris Renke](http://chrisrenke.com/spans/), for your tabluar `Toast`. However, I do not know what process is responsible for rendering the `Toast` content, and if that's not your process, your custom spans will not work.

Comment: Well it's the toast code is in a main activity method that is triggered by a button in my view.

Comment: @Kaspar: Yes, but a `Toast` lives independently of the `Activity` that displays it. You can see this by quickly pressing BACK on the activity for a `LENGTH_LONG` `Toast` -- the `Toast` will remain on-screen. That's why I am not completely certain if custom span classes will work.